# How to find out what is taking up space in the Linux cache memory?

Tags: linux, memory

Which Linux tool can help me to find out what is taking up space in the Linux cache memory ?

Is there any log or something which can tell me all memory operations performed by kernel like what is being put into the cache and what is being removed from the cache ?

Comment: which linux you are using

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, but I wanted to know in general because we are also using other flavors of Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Would command `slabtop` be helpful for you?